# SubMenu items not displayed on if( is_page(array())) statement with addclass function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, if-statement

Hello I am trying to add an addclass function if else statement so the toggled submenu stays open on the specified pages.

Current nav opens and closes without the if statement but once added the if( is_page(array())) statement the whole thing stops working.

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    if( is_page( array( 'edit-account', 'edit-address', 'payment-method', 'orders' ) ) ){
         $$(document).on('load', function(){
            $(".group-opener").addClass("open");
         });
         $('.group-opener').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(300);
            $(this).next('ul').stop(true, false, true).slideToggle(300);
            return false;
        });
    }
    else {
        $("a.group-opener").on("click", function(){
            $(".group-opener").toggleClass("open");
        });
        $('.group-opener').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(300);
            $(this).next('ul').stop(true, false, true).slideToggle(300);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

html

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/my-account/">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/my-account/order-a-kit/">Order A Kit</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/my-account/subscriptions/">My Subscriptions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="group-custom-group">
                <a class="group-opener" href="#">Account Details</a>
                <ul class="myaccount-submenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/my-account/edit-account/">Edit Account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/my-account/edit-address/">Edit Addresses</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/my-account/payment-methods/">Payment methods</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/my-account/orders/">Order History</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/my-account/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=b7f9a60e3d">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

css

```
a.group-opener:after {
    content: '\f078';
    font-family: 'fontAwesome';
    padding-left: 10px;
}
a.group-opener.open:after {
    content: '\f077';
    font-family: 'fontAwesome';
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.myaccount-submenu {
    display: none;
} 
.myaccount-submenu.open {
    display: block;
}
.stay-open {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Everything after the else statement works fine, the menu just closes when you are on the submenu item urls and that is what I am aiming to fix.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you in advance!

Comment: Change `$$(document)` to `$(document)` on line 4

Comment: @jtheman that still causes both if and else statements to not trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help I was able to fix this with  jQuery

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on('click', '.group-opener', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(300);
        $(this).next('ul').stop(true, false, true).slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
    var pages = ['edit-account', 'edit-address', 'payment-method', 'orders'],
        url = window.location.href,
        in_page = false;
    $.each(pages, function(idx, item){
        if(url.indexOf('my-account/'+item)>-1){
            in_page = true;
        }
    });
    if(in_page){
        $('.group-opener').addClass('open').next('ul').css('display','block').parent().siblings().find('ul').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

added a pages variable and $.each(pages, function(idx, item) to validate in_page = true

The if(in_page) is so the sub items load completely opened as apposed to slidetoggle on (document).ready

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing PHP and JS code. If you are using the jQuery code in a PHP script (guessing Wordpress) you can add the `if - else` condition with PHP tags for all the PHP code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

<?php if( is_page( array( 'edit-account', 'edit-address', 'payment-method', 'orders' ) ) ){ ?>
     $(window).on('load', function(){
        $(".group-opener").addClass("open");
     });
     $('.group-opener').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(300);
        $(this).next('ul').stop(true, false, true).slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
  }
  <?php else { ?>
      $("a.group-opener").on("click", function(){
        $(".group-opener").toggleClass("open");
      });
      $('.group-opener').click(function() {
          $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(300);
          $(this).next('ul').stop(true, false, true).slideToggle(300);
          return false;
      });
   <?php  } ?>
});
```

Note that you can only add PHP syntax in PHP scripts, so if the jQuery is defined elsewhere (IE in an js-file) then this solution won't work. For Wordpress I suggest you to put your JS in separate files and adding it trough `functions.php`. Here is an example code, then you put the always open menu in `special_menu.js` and the default menu code in `normal_menu.js`:

```
function page_menu_script() {
    if( is_page( array( 'edit-account', 'edit-address', 'payment-method', 'orders' ) ) ){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 'path_to_js/special_menu.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
    else {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 'path_to_js/normal_menu.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    } 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'page_menu_script' );
```